# Can I Create sorted filter shelf based off corresponding ID column

Tags: sorting, filter, tableau-api

Tableau version: 10.2

I'm trying to order/sort my filter shelf based on a corresponding ID column that is specific from company to company. Currently, it sorts alphabetically since it's a string value. In our database, we have an ID column that is ordered to the preference of the company...in ascending order (lowest value id = first value to show in filter shelf).

I know I can manually order the filter shelf, but it varies for company to company. When I base it off of the value ID (based off another field), it makes me aggregate the Id in some way...count, sum, which isn't what I'd like.

I have attached a workbook with sample data for one company. Other companies could have more or less values, but will contain a unique value ID. Below is snapshot of the issue and what I'm hoping to achieve.

I could use concatenation, but don't want the ID values to show on the filter shelf. I've explored LOD functions, but they require an aggregation.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution that I can think of, other than concatenation, is creating a worksheet and use it as a filter. The filter sheet includes the "Company", "Value ID" columns (both hidden). Then you can create a dashboard and show the sheets side-by-side.

[image: Screenshot Example]

Comment: but how does this help custom sort my filter I'm showing? That is my end goal. In my original table, I don't have value ID on the table, nor will I. I want to sort the value filter which is being shown off of the value ID column in Ascending order.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to sort the quick filter box? One option I can think of, other than concatenation, is using a worksheet as a filter. See the edits.

Comment: What @YingSquared is saying is trick Tableau into using a worksheet as a filter. Build a dashboard with your source sheet. Create a second sheet that is filtered how you want it. Then create a filter action in your dashboard so that when you click on the filter sheet, it filters your source sheet. See https://www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/kb/filters_actions.html.